# Control does not go inside while loop [results next] even if results has values

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb

I am performing action of search query using FMDB in iOS. If I print the value of results,It shows some value but control does not go in while loop.Here is my code.

`tempStr` is the value of search box:

```
FMResultSet *results=[db executeQuery:@"select * From Notes where Note_Title LIKE '@%'",tempStr];
marrDataDB=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Results for query : %@ ",results);
while ([results next])
{
    NSLog(@"I am in WHile LOOP");
    searchHelper=[[dbHelper alloc]init];

    helper.nTitle=[results stringForColumn:@"Note_Title"];
    searchHelper.nDesc=[results stringForColumn:@"Note_Desc"];
    searchHelper.nATime= [results stringForColumn:@"Note_A_Time"];

    [marrDataDB addObject:searchHelper];

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is real code then the query has a typo and should be:

```
@"select * From Notes where Note_Title LIKE '%@'"
```

so I guess you get a valid `FMResultSet` object back which you log but which contains no actual results because the query didn't match anything.

Comment: So the whole premise of the question is invalid.

Comment: but If I run in sqlite database this query works but not works in Xcode programming

Comment: Which request? The point is your injection of `tempStr` to the query is incorrect in your code

Comment: I am also getting correct value of tempStr if I Nslog it.

Comment: Log `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * From Notes where Note_Title LIKE '@%'",tempStr]` - is it what you expect?

Comment: Yes,I am trying to fetch other database field from Note_Title, This query works but control doesn't go inside while loop so other fields can not get fetch..

Comment: Yupp.I have run it and If you see my Question then I have also NSLog in while loop but that doesn't print "I am in while loop" but prints the value of results just before while loop

Comment: I mean the NSLog in my comment above - you need to prove that your query is right before you wonder if the result is right

Comment: Yes, I am not getting perfect value in this..Result I am getting is --> select * From Notes where Note_Title LIKE '@'" but I can't figure out why this query doesn't help me.

Comment: Because you typed it wrongly, read my answer carefully and cut and paste my code

Answer (score 1):

Just check out do you get any results from database or not

```
NSUInteger count = [db intForQuery:@"select count(Note_Title) From Notes where Note_Title LIKE '@%'",tempStr];
NSLog(@"count :%d",count);
```

Comment: Yes i have 4 results in database.

Comment: But did you determine that with code, or by looking at the DB yourself?

Comment: I am performing query using FMDatabase and intForQuery doesn't work for it..Getting error of "No visible interface for FMDatabase declares the selector intforQuery"

Comment: If you copied the error message then you misspelt the selector name and have another typo

Comment: Make sure to include the FMDatabaseAdditions.h header file to use intForQuery